# How do I let the user swipe a CarouselPage when it contains a ListView?

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gesture-recognition, xamarin.winphone

In my Xamarin.Forms app for Windows Phone 8.1, we have a number of pages that the user can swipe between using a `CarouselPage`.  One of these pages contains a `ListView` that fills the screen, and when that page selected the user can't swipe any more; the action is interpreted by the list view as a tap in one of its cells.  What can I do so that horizontal swipes will still change page in the carousel?  I still want vertical swipes to scroll the list view.

Comment: Have you tried using CarouselView  instead of CarouselPage? CarouselPage page will go obsolete soon

Comment: You don't need taps on the `ListView`? Check out the `InputTransparent` property on it

Comment: @BraveHeart it doesn't look like CarouselView is available in the Xamarin Forms stable release yet.  Do you know when it will be available?

Comment: @Gerald I do need taps on the ListView.  But I want horizontal swipes, and only horizontal swipes, to be captured by the CarouselPage, so that it can scroll.

Comment: You can add Carousel View as Nuget. https://blog.xamarin.com/flip-through-items-with-xamarin-forms-carouselview/

Comment: @Rohit thanks. That doesn't look like a replacement for CarouselPage though; it looks like it's for swiping between views, not swiping between pages.

Comment: I don't think there is any way you could get it working in any simple way. The touch will be handled by listview even before it would be recognised as a swipe as list is the top view and corousel page is only underneath it. If you can instead of tap use a button to set the listview selected item, then you can set inputTransparent as false.

Comment: @Rohit so if I set InputTransparent on the ListView, and use buttons in the list view cells, will the buttons receive the taps?

Comment: Yes, You are setting input transparent for only the listview. Button is a separate control and should receive the click event without any issues.

Comment: @Rohit is that true even if the Button is inside the ListView?  I believe that will be the case if the Button is part of the ListView's template.

Comment: The button should be part of listview itemtemplate.

Comment: @Rohit I set InputTransparent on the ListView, and it had no effect.  The cells still do their little animation when I try to swipe.

Comment: @Simon You can disable the effect to be less like this:
`listView.ItemTapped += (sender, e) =>
{
 tripsListView.SelectedItem = null;
};`

Comment: @Mario that doesn't stop the cell from intercepting the tap. It just resets the selected item to null after the cell has been selected.

Comment: @Simon well man obviously you are doing something really hard to do :)  do you know of any design with this solution ? think about it like this . What if the listview would support a swipe ? so what would the swipe be applied on the listItem of the page? Maybe you can use tabbedPage instead

Comment: @BraveHeart TabbedPage works fine on Windows Phone but is utterly unusable on Windows Desktop.

Comment: @Simon oh you have really great ambition for juicing Xamarin.Froms :)  I like the spirit , but you know that the more platforms you target the more compromises you make. 
  My advice is in case of the listpage appears, have two buttons one on the left side and the other on the right side to do the swiping .
Otherwise have an empty area below the listview so the user can swipe the page from it . Actually i think you can unify all the pages to have such "Swipe Area" . You could place a nice image there maybe :)

Comment: @Rohit I upgraded to Xamarin.Forms 2.3 and now InputTransparent works!  If you add that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Simon - Thanks, for getting back. I have added the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not be directly achieved in the Xamarin Forms project because when there is a list view available all the taps, gestures, etc will handled by the listview itself. 
Only the gestures which are not handled by the top most layout/control will be passed into the controls/layouts beneath it. 
So in your case the listview handles all the gestures and nothing is passed to your carousel page.

The only work around for the problem that I can think of is, setting the `InputTransparent` property of the listview as `true`. In that case no gestures will be handled by the listview and everything will be passed on to the carousel page. 
But since you need to have the selected item and open the detail page from the list view, what you can do is have a button in the listview item template and handle the click of the button. Since button is a separate control and on top of listview, the setting `InputTransparent` wont affect the button click event/command binding.

*EDIT* : As per OP's experience he is able to access the selected item and all other features of listview even after setting the InputTransparent.

Comment: I've set `InputTransparent` and the ListView is still working as I would hope, even without setting buttons for its content.  I can still scroll it and tap items, but I can also swipe to change the carousel.  Thanks!

Comment: You mean you get listview selected item, even after setting the InputTransparent?

Comment: Yeah - I can still scroll the list view and select items.